# Stream video from local video file VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, video

I'm making a remote-assistant program that should send screenshots to my server. I use TCP. The problem is that the client will send packets at high speed and if my server is slowly I will not be able to kkep up with the coming images and I will get an memory overflow exception(because one image takes up to 30 MB in memory). I came up with an idea: to buffer the images in avi file on disk (like many video-audio streaming applications do-something like MJPEG mode). I found the perfect library for this:DirectShow and Video from AForge. 
   Basically ,I write to an avi file while reading from it (in FIFO style).
This is the test project for streaming(I write a couple of pictures to an avi and trying to read it):

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim thr As New Thread(AddressOf write)
    Dim videowriter As New VideoFileWriter
    Dim WithEvents vid As New AVIReader
    Dim WithEvents vidd As DirectShow.FileVideoSource
    Dim cc As Long, used As Boolean
    Dim aa As FilterInfoCollection, bb As New VideoCaptureDevice

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "/video/stream.avi") Then File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "/video/stream.avi")
        thr.Start()
        Thread.Sleep(1000) 'wait so that the avi contains some frames

        vidd = New DirectShow.FileVideoSource(Application.StartupPath & "/video/stream.avi")
        vidd.Start()
    End Sub

    Sub a(sender As Object, args As NewFrameEventArgs) Handles vidd.NewFrame
        draw(args.Frame.Clone)
        Thread.Sleep(100) 'wait again
    End Sub


    Sub draw(ByRef pic As Bitmap)
        If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        End If

        PictureBox1.Image = pic
    End Sub

    Sub write()
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Dim crop_bit As New Bitmap(320, 240), bit As Bitmap
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(crop_bit)

        videowriter.Open(Application.StartupPath & "/video/stream.avi", 320, 240, 100, VideoCodec.MPEG4)

        For Each fil As String In Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath & "/pictures")
            count += 1
            Debug.Print(count)

            bit = Image.FromFile(fil)

            g.DrawImage(bit, 0, 0, 320, 240)

            videowriter.WriteVideoFrame(crop_bit)
            bit.Dispose()
        Next
        'STOP..here
        videowriter.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

But it is not working. No error. It creates the file..the video everything but it shows no images on the picturebox. It seems that when it writes to the avi it open as WriteOnly and doesn't allow the reading(maybe?). Is there any way around? I heard about queues but it is still stored in memory..it has to be on disk. Is it an option to make my own MJPEG-like file (store every image inside this file within some delimiters/header)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

30Mb is huge for a screen shot.

You might consider finding out why it's so large, and either fixing the problem or compressing the image. It's unlikely anybody with a normal home internet connection or even an average businesses connection can stream 30Mb frames.

If your server can not keep up, it will not help to stream the screen shots and in fact, will make it slower because of the added overhead.

To fix your problem, you need to drop frames or reduce the image size significantly when your server or network connection is too slow. Streaming will not help.

For What It's Worth, actual streaming servers transcode the media at multiple resolutions and framerates, for exactly this reason. Someone with a fiber internet connection might be able to stream full 1080P or better video, while someone on a 2g phone might need to be scaled back to (180x320?) and a couple of frames/second, however this is probably not acceptable if you're dealing with screen shots that need to be readable.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. But I reviewed all of my code (from tcp class). It seems that the picture box does that . I added the part with picturebox1.image.dispose but the GC is still called continously because it uses too much ram (I use visual studio 2015 and I can see when it's called). I think I make somewhere dublicates. I'll search further.

Comment: But that's not the real problem. The problem is the reading/writing. Now I'm creating my own mjpeg-like format. This will cost me another day. I have already created 2 other classes to suit my needs.

Comment: The problem isn't reading or writing. The problem is that you're trying to put 2 tons of fertilizer into a 1 ton pickup truck. You just don't have the capacity to do this. However now that you mentioned you're using BMPs, I can tell you that you couldn't find a less efficient way of handling the image than this. the first thig I'd do is find a much better format. Perhaps PNG. http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bitmaps/

Comment: "The problem is the reading/writing. Now I'm creating my own mjpeg-like format. This will cost me another day." this is going to take a lot longer than a day.